# Radio buttons built with ngFor work. Identical set build manually don't Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have build two sets of identical radio buttons. However only the set built using a ngFor loop is working for me.

I am using identical syntax so can't figure out where I am making a mistake.

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qs7qw9)

```html
<form>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="crabColour == crab.colour" *ngFor="let crab of crabs; let i = index">
      <input type="radio" name="shiftSubType" autocomplete="off"  [(ngModel)]="crabColour" [value]="crab.colour"> {{crab.colour}}
    </label>
  </div><br>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons2" id="trainingRadio">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="duckColour == 'red'">
      <input type="radio" name="training" id="trainingYesRadio" autocomplete="off"  [(ngModel)]="duckColour" [value]="red"> red
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="duckColour == 'yellow'">
      <input type="radio" name="training" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="duckColour" [value]="yellow"> yellow
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

By 'work' I mean when either of the second set of buttons is pressed it doesn't stay pressed.

Comment: I don't have them for either of them. Why does the first one work still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In manually added code :

Change `[value]` to `value`

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-ngfor)**

> `[value]="yellow"`  will consider yellow as variable/executable-part and try to eval that.

```
[value]="crab.colour" // here it will get value from crab.colour

[value]="yellow" // here it will try to fetch value form yellow , but yellow itself is value , so you should use value only
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes it. Can you please explain why it needs to be `[value]` for the first set and just `value` for the second?

Comment: Alternatively, `[value]="'yellow'"` - if that helps make it clearer?

Comment: yep, makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Got a 2 min timeout for some reason. Just waiting for that to go.

Comment: @charsi , Happy Coding :) BTW